# ref table with FKs and cascade

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, cascade

[image]

```
  CREATE TABLE [clients] (
    id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
      CONSTRAINT PK___CLIENTS#id
        PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED,
    name NVARCHAR(250) NOT NULL
      CONSTRAINT UQ___CLIENTS#name
        UNIQUE (name)
  );
```

```
  CREATE TABLE [contacts] (
    id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
      CONSTRAINT PK___CONTACTS#id
        PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED,
    client_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
      CONSTRAINT FK___CONTACTS#client_id___CLIENTS#id
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [clients] (id)
          ON DELETE CASCADE
          ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    name NVARCHAR(250) NOT NULL
      CONSTRAINT UQ___CONTACTS#name$client_id
        UNIQUE (name, client_id)
  );
```

```
  CREATE TABLE [addresses] (
    id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
      CONSTRAINT PK___ADDRESSES#id
        PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED,
    client_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
      CONSTRAINT FK___ADDRESSES#client_id___CLIENTS#id
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [clients] (id)
          ON DELETE CASCADE
          ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    name NVARCHAR(250) NOT NULL
      CONSTRAINT UQ___ADDRESSES#name$client_id
        UNIQUE (name, client_id)
  );
```

```
  CREATE TABLE [contacts_addresses] (
    contact_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
      CONSTRAINT FK___CONTACTS_ADDRESSES#contact_id___CONTACTS#id
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [contacts] (id)
          ON DELETE CASCADE
          ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    address_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
      CONSTRAINT FK___CONTACTS_ADDRESSES#address_id___ADDRESSES#id
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [addresses] (id)
          ON DELETE CASCADE
          ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT PK___CONTACTS_ADDRESSES#contact_id$address_id
      PRIMARY KEY (contact_id, address_id)
  );
```

I get the error on creating the reference table...

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK___CONTACTS_ADDRESSES#address_id___ADRESSES#id' on table 'contacts_addresses' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint or index.

I think it's because both parent tables are linked with the CLIENTS table, but why isn't that possible?

1. e.g. I wish to delete a client record, then the contacts and also the addresses of the client should be delete then. If this happens, the referenced records (matching contact_id & address_id) should be deleted, too.
2. e.g. I wish to delete a contact record, then all referenced records with that contact_id should be deleted.
3. e.g. I wish to delete a address record, then all referenced records with that address_id should be deleted.

But how?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: SQL Server simply does not support that.

Comment: If you must have behaviour like this, either use SP's to handle the deletes gracefully (and in the correct order), or use `INSTEAD OF` triggers. Personally, I would prefer the former.

Comment: Okay, thank you all :/ Soooo bad that Microsoft SQL Server does not support this. :(
Then I try to do that client-deletes by myself, or better by my CORS api.

Comment: it's not really bad that it *doesn't* support something that has the potential to break the database...

Comment: @Froschkoenig84 . . . You can do this using `delete` triggers.

Comment: @Larmu Only a potential. ;) But most devs build clean and tested solutions. (somtimes :P )